# Powershell Backgroundworker

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Can anyone give me an example of how to use BackgroundWorker in Powershell?

I want to write something so when a new tab is selected in my Powershell GUI app, it will switch to the tab with a "please wait" message displayed, then run some checks in a BackgroundWorker thread, and then update.

Is this possible in Powershell? All the Googling I've done points to c# or VB.Net.

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

If the background thread is going to use a PowerShell pipeline to do its work, then I would avoid using BackgroundWorker. It wouldn't be tied to a PowerShell Runspace.  Try doing your async processing using `Register-ObjectEvent` e.g.:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $tabItem Loaded -Action { <do bg work here> }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Start-Process`:

```
$scriptPath = "c:\script.ps1"
$allArgs = "/someOrNoArgsHere /moreArgs"
$backgroundProcess = Start-Process -FilePath $scriptPath -ArgumentList $allArgs -Wait -Passthru -WindowStyle Hidden
$backgroundProcess.WaitForExit()
$backgroundProcess.ExitCode
```

Or you could use a one-liner:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\script.ps1" -ArgumentList "/someOrNoArgsHere /moreArgs" -Wait -Passthru -WindowStyle Hidden
```